# Separate String Equation into Separate Variables in Java

Tags: android, string, sorting, converters, operator-keyword

Is it possible to take a string such as "1+21-32*43/54", and separate it into the variables:

```
a=1; 
b=21;
c=32; 
d=43; 
e=54;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to find the digits and separate them out regardless of the operator's (+,-,etc) then you could use

```
"1+21-32*43/54".match(/\D/)
```

to get an array of all the numbers

Comment: What if I want to also keep track of the operators and their locations?

Comment: hmm, id say use a similar regex for finding all non-digits of the string, and then you'll have two arrays, one of all the digits in order and one of all the operators in order. regex could be googled cant think off top of my head (long day)

Answer (score 0):

In groovy it's easy:

```
"1+21-32*43/54".split(/[^0-9]/)
```

In Java you can use the same regex.